# .NET Core API - Unknown Column in field list

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm new to C# / .NET Core and I'm trying to create a Web API. I have 2 models; Community & Rank

Community:

```
public class Community
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long FrontId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CommunityId")]
    public virtual ICollection<Rank> Ranks { get; set; } 
}
```

Rank:

```
public class Rank
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long CommunityId { get; set; } [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; } [Required]
    public string Prefix { get; set; }
    public virtual Community Community { get; set; }
}
```

I have my context set up like so:

```
public class CommunityContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Community> Communities { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Rank> Ranks { get; set; }

    public CommunityContext(DbContextOptions<CommunityContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        //Communities

        builder.Entity<Community>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(c => c.Id);
            entity.Property(c => c.Name).IsRequired();
            entity.Property(c => c.FrontId).IsRequired();
            // entity.Property(c => c.Ranks).IsRequired(false);
            entity.HasMany(c => c.Ranks).WithOne().HasForeignKey(c => c.CommunityId).IsRequired();
        });

        //Ranks

        builder.Entity<Rank>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(r => r.Id);
            entity.Property(r => r.Name).IsRequired();
            entity.Property(r => r.Prefix).IsRequired();
            entity.Property(r => r.CommunityId).HasColumnName("CommunityId").IsRequired();
            // entity.HasOne(r => r.Community).WithMany(s => s.Ranks);
        });
    }
}
```

I've done my database migrations etc, and when creating new entries, all works as expected currently, however trying to `GET` either communities or ranks returns the error:

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unknown column 'r.CommunityId1' in 'field list'

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Configurations should be like this:

...

```
    //Communities

    builder.Entity<Community>(entity =>
    {
        builder.ToTable("Community");
        builder.HasKey(c => c.Id);
        builder.Property(c => c.Id).HasColumnName("CommunityId").ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
        entity.Property(c => c.Name).IsRequired();
        entity.Property(c => c.FrontId).IsRequired();
        // entity.Property(c => c.Ranks).IsRequired(false);
        entity.HasMany(c => c.Ranks).WithOne().HasForeignKey(c => c.CommunityId).IsRequired();
    });

    //Ranks

    builder.Entity<Rank>(entity =>
    {
        builder.ToTable("Rank");
        builder.HasKey(r => r.Id);
        builder.Property(r => r.Id).HasColumnName("RankId").ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
        entity.Property(r => r.Name).IsRequired();
        entity.Property(r => r.Prefix).IsRequired();
        entity.Property(r => r.CommunityId).HasColumnName("CommunityId").IsRequired();
        // entity.HasOne(r => r.Community).WithMany(s => s.Ranks);
    });
```

...